# aggregate `$lookup` is not working in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

when i am using $lookup in my collections i am getting following output which is wrong

This the output:

```
{"_pipeline":[{"$project":{"fulldetails":{"$concat":["$associate_name"," ","$associate_no"]},"outlets":"$outl"}},{"$lookup":{"from":"outlets","localField":"_id","foreignField":"associate_id","as":"outl"}}],"options":{}}
```

And this is the query

```
  var data=Associate.aggregate([{
        $project: {
          "fulldetails": {
            $concat: ["$associate_name", " ", "$associate_no"]
          },
          "outlets": "$outl"
        }
      }, {
        $lookup: {
          from: "outlets",
          localField: "_id",
          foreignField: "associate_id",
          as: "outl"
        }
      }])
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: In which way is it wrong? What is it supposed to look like?

Comment: i need combined output from two collections,i am trying to achieve through lookup and it is showing following error

Comment: please also post your schema model

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both foreign field and local field must be of same type than only $lookup will work

In your case

local field is **_id**

foreign field is **associate_id**

> if _id is ObjectID and associate_id is ObjectID then only it will work
>
> if _id is String and associate_id is String then only it will work
>
> if _id is ObjectID and associate_id is String then it will not work
>
> if _id is String and associate_id is ObjectID then it will not work

Answer (score 0):

To build on Ratan's answer,

### How do you make your fields to be of similar type?

---

You can use the `$toObjectId` and `$set` operator to change your field values to a MongoDB `ObjectId` object and compare.

```
Model.aggregate([
  { $set: { local_id: { $toObjectId: '$local_id' } } },
  { $set: { foreign_id: { $toObjectId: '$foreign_id' } } },
])
```

In the example above, I am setting the value of `local_id` and `foreign_id` to be `ObjectId` for similar type comparison.